# SP initiated logout not redirected to relaystate

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

I am using oneLogin java tool kit to signin against the ssocircle.It worked fine. How ever, when I click the logout. I am not logout out of the IDP and its not redirected back to the relaystate.

**LogoutRequest**

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com"
    ID="ONELOGIN_7e0b2553-81ab-4b0c-929f-803096cfa28d" 
IssueInstant="2017-09-01T08:59:20Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer>debug/honeywell.com</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
        SPNameQualifier="debug/honey.com">https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Please guide how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Kind regards,
Ajay

Comment: Does the IdP reply anything? Is there any error at the IdP side?

Comment: No, there is no error.It shows the IDP metadata xml page.The response code says OK.Status 200.

Comment: maybe you set as SLO URL the URL where the IdP publish its metadata... https://idp.ssocircle.com doesnt seem the right value.

Comment: After adding SessionIndex to the SAMLLogout request ,
 it worked. <samlp:SessionIndex>_780ec24f-7844-4526-a3be-89c58b3aa598</samlp:SessionIndex>